# js.Function2, how to?

Tags: scala, d3.js, higher-order-functions, scala.js

I am trying to port some d3.js application to Scala.js, just for the sake of learning. But currently I am kind of stuck.

JS:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
```

How can I transform that to scala.js? I know I need a `js.Function2[Node, Double, js.Tuple2[Double,Double]` but I have no idea how to produce it.

For `js.Function1` it's easy, like so:

```
private def test: (Event) => Unit = (e: dom.Event) => {
    ()
}
```

Using `"org.singlespaced" %%% "scalajs-d3" % "0.3.3"`

Comment: "I know I need a `js.Function2[Node, Double, js.Tuple2[Double,Double]`" Where do you know that from? Are you using some specific Scala.js library for d3.js? What is the definition of `projection`? From the JS code it looks to me more like a `js.Function1[Point, js.Tuple2[Double, Double]]`. If you really need a `js.Function2` like you say, it should have the form `{ (node: Node, dbl: Double) => js.Tuple2(someX, someY) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the same thing, only it takes two parameters. The cognate to your example would be:

```
private val test2: (Node, Double) => js.Tuple2[Double, Double] = (n:Node, d:Double) => {
    (1.2, 3.5)
}
```

Although it would be more typical to state that as just:

```
private def test2(n:Node, d:Double):js.Tuple2[Double, Double] = {
    (1.2, 3.5)
}
```

Inlined, it would be *something* like:

```
val diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection((n:Node, d:Double) => js.Tuple2(something.y, something.x));
```

The "something" is because I don't understand how your JS example comes out as a `js.Function2` -- a `Function2` takes 2 parameters, and your example only shows 1. Are the `x` and `y` fields of `Node`?

Comment: I tried `val diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection((n: Node,  d: Double) => (d, d))`
Sadly that gives me: `Type mismatch, expected: Function2[Node, Double, Tuple2[Double, Double]], actual (dom.Node, Double) => (Double, Double)`

Comment: Based on the comment from @sjrd above (who knows the system much more deeply than I), it sounds like we're expecting too much of the implicit converters.  Try making that last bit `js.Tuple2(d, d)` -- I'll edit my answer that way.